# In Score Attack mode, what affects the score?

Tags: bastion

I'm currently working on completing the game (in Steam, so 100% achievements) and there's just a few left, one that implies playing in Score Attack mode.

So I wonder how I could maximize that, and especially what does affect the score? (speed? DPS? shards looted? XP? something else?)

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/605743-bastion/61810184):

> Realistically though, Score Attack I think takes the sum of the highest scores of each area that you've been in. Meaning that it's worth going back to older levels once you have leveled up and gotten your loadout checked.

Basically, you just need to go maximize your scores across all the levels, since the total score is just the sum of all your high scores, especially the earlier levels, now that you have access to better equipment.